# Count pixels on the render target

Tags: android, shader, opengl-es-2.0

Using OpenGL ES 2.0 and Galaxy S4 phone, I have a Render Target 1024x1024 RGBA8888 where some textures are rendered each frame. I need to calculate how much red RGBA(1, 0, 0, 1) pixels was rendered on the render target (twice a second).

The main problem is that getting the texture from the GPU is very performance-expensive (~300-400 ms), and freezes are not applicable for my application.

I know about OES_shader_image_atomic extension for atomic counters (simply to increment some value when frag shader works), but it's available only in OpenGL ES 3.1 (and later), I have to stick to ES 2.0.

Is there any common solution I missed?

Comment: You didn't mention what you're using the count for but if the value is going to end up being fed back into the GPU then you're almost always better off jumping through whatever hoops are necessary to avoid getting the CPU involved at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can try is to "reduce" texture in question to a significantly smaller one and read back to CPU that one (which should be less expensive performance-wise). For example, you can split your texture into squares N by N (where N is preferably is a power of two), then render a "whole screen" quad into a 1024/N by 1024/N texture with a fragment shader that sums number of red pixels in corresponding square:

```
sampler2D texture;

void main(void) {
    vec2 offset = N * gl_FragCoord.xy;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (float x = 0.; x < float(N); x += 1) {
        for(float y = 0.; y < float(N); y += 1) {
            if (texture2D(texture, (offset + vec2(x, y)) / 1024.) == vec4(1, 0, 0, 1)) {
                cnt += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    gl_FragColor = vec4((cnt % 256) / 255., ((cnt / 256) % 256) / 255., /* ... */);
}
```

Also remember that `readPixels` synchronously wait till GPU is done with all previously issued draws to the texture. So it may be beneficial to have two textures,
on each frame one is being rendered to, and the other is being read from. The next frame you swap them. That will somewhat delay obtaining the desired data, but should eliminate some freezes.

Comment: It works great - subdivided to 4 512x512 subtextures and iterated them. Marked as an answer.